# Kendo Treeview handle empty HierarchicalDataSource

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Is there a way to handle empty HierarchicalDataSource for Kendo treeview?

```
var outletDataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "./getOutletOwners.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: function(){
                            return {
                                method: "getOutlet"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id : "outletID",
                        hasChildren: false,
                    }
                }
            });

var outletTreeView = $('#outletTree').kendoTreeView({
                checkboxes: true,
                dataSource: outletDataSource,
                dataBound: function(){
                    this.expand('.k-item');
                },
                dataTextField: ["outletName"]
            }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

The data source fetch data remotely. It could load fine if there is data to fetch but if there is no data it just could not load properly(it shows loading icon forever). It just show this error in the console "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null**".

Comment: Return an empty array instead of null.

Comment: @GaloisGirl thanks for the tips. I've change the codes so it returns empty array instead of null and it works.